# Error installing RubyGems on Linux

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am getting error installing rubygems on Linux as shown below:

```
[redmine@mail rubygems-2.6.12]$ pwd
/binaries/rubygems-2.6.12
[redmine@mail rubygems-2.6.12]$ sudo ruby setup.rb
[sudo] password for redmine:
<internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

Below are my ruby details.

```
[redmine@mail rubygems-2.6.12]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
[redmine@mail rubygems-2.6.12]$ which ruby
/usr/sbin/ruby
```

I am following this document for my installation: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Redmine_on_CentOS_installation_HOWTO#Check-installation

Need help troubleshoot the error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have used option 1 to install ruby and installed ruby 1.8.7, right?
I never had to install rubygems seperately, and certainly not when using a 1.9 or 2.* version of ruby.
Why don't you use a higher version of ruby and/or skip the whole installing of rubygems?

Comment: when you plan to use ruby more than once, maybe installing ruby with rvm (option 2) is preferable. Rvm is really great in combination with gem sets.

Comment: Yes, I used step 1 to install Ruby but I installed the latest Ruby version 2.4.1. Does it come pre-installed with rubygems ? If so, how can I confirm that I have rubygems installed on my system ?     `code`   [redmine@mail bin]$ /ticket/tools/binaries/ruby-2.4.1/bin/gem -v
<internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'

Comment: you can check by requiring a gem that is installed. Most convenient with irb. Using ruby 1.8 for example. I know gem ncurses is installed. Then in irb (interactive ruby shell), when I issue "require 'ncurses'" then "require 'rubygems'" then require 'ncurses'", I get an error message and two 'true' replies respectively.. When I use ruby > 1.8, I can skip the "require 'rubygems'" and require ncurses right away.